# .xib not loading right (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xib

For some reason when I load a new view (from a .xib) it'll load the class files, BUT NOT the .xib!!

Here's my code:

```
login *lo =[[login alloc] initWithNibName:@"login" bundle:nil];
self.log = lo;
UIViewController *loginview = log;
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn forView:self.view cache:YES];
[loginview viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self viewWillDisappear:YES];
[self.view insertSubview:loginview.view atIndex:0];
[self viewDidDisappear:YES];
[loginview viewDidAppear:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[log release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068368/why-doesnt-initwithnibname-work-for-my-uiviewcontroller-subclass) discusses what you're experiencing? Sorry if I misunderstood your question, it's kind of low on the details.

Comment: kinda, however after checking everything it seems that none of that stuff is the problem

Comment: Ok, after some debugging it turns out that when I run that code it doesn't add the view (login), instead it loads the window (in the delegate)