# Why does the view nib doesn't open after cell is selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I created the nib file and I did all the connections correctly. When I run the application and select a cell, the new nib doesn't open at all. Please help!

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Get the selected country
NSString *selectedCountry = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"you pressed for this."];

//Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] 
                                      initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

dvController.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
dvController = nil;

}
```

Comment: Check this SO post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068368/why-doesnt-initwithnibname-work-for-my-uiviewcontroller-subclass [It doesn't load the view...](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/76635-doesnt-load-view.html)

Comment: Release `selectedCountry` or you leak. Is it on a navigation controller? Try `NSLog(@"%@ %@", self.navigationController, dvController);` immediately after `pushViewController:animated:` method and let us know the result.

Comment: which mistake do you get? also `dvController = nil;` do not need because you delete dvController from memory before.

Comment: @Deepak, I released selectedCountry in DetailViewController.m and tried what you told me but no luck!

Comment: @Sherilyn, I actually don't get any errors. It builds perfectly fine but the nib doesn't load at all when I click on the cell. I also tried deleting the dvController = nil but it didn't do anything. Thanks though!

Comment: @Jovany I wanted to know what it printed on the console. I didn't think it would fix the issue. :)

Comment: @Deepak, nothing shows up on the console. It simply prints session started.... and thats about it.

Comment: Your code is fine. Try to re-check connection in IB, name of NIB file. Also create a test view in `DetailViewController` and add it to self.view to see that your controller is really loaded. Do this in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`. Create breakpoints in these methods, and look what happens.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like (based on no output being logged for the `NSLog` statement) that you don't have your `delegate` set properly as it would've otherwise logged `null` or some object value. You need to recheck your IB connections or if you've done it programmatically then do `tableView.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] 
                                      initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

dvController.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
dvController = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't both release the `dvController` AND set it to `nil` - do only one.

Comment: Just to reiterate, releasing is necessary to adhere to memory management rules. `nil`-ing however is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to load the detailvewcontroller from a listviewcontroller. And the table view is a member of listviewcontroller.

Posssible reason for the issue.

If you are adding listviewcontroller.view as a subview to any other viewcontollers view then

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES]; don't work.

So you should get an instance of your app delegate and do the following.

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate .navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```

Check around this. If this is not a reason for your issue then please let me know the console output Deepak asked you.